# How to validate json token generated by Keycloak using golang

Tags: go, token, keycloak

I want to validate a json token using golang, but I just see the error `Error parsing or validating token: key is of invalid type`. Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func main() {
    // example token to validate
    tokenString := "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6MXdOWU9YVFRpd2RhQjJyS1NqNElrUG1YTDJHbXVTOVFRNERJeXpWbWlrIn0.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.vqFWx5mMESEMww8E5t1J8ZmoCw1R9qv1qlgaYaG7FQcd8B_sN223cDYMoqJF5y-Xv9zaJ094fUmyDtJHv-ZTkxw3R9AtjG0cCjqMxgBn1X2irlNYEmR5ZX73YXDUxY6XuABLyTGdh00bEcaUIyFR1Pver2UDjMf2okcV1FgEd0Z_94j4pjqtcY0nbsWIKnLoVoor7QV6ytWRpMG25DvrSVxciaOpogOHlUhaWtTfMz-mvfFg64i_S6rIuT84APnVe6weAuj92YS6bUzBif_gcgNeMdLrJChxWdPMK9G5mDAgLOqUv-X5fPOw1arigInV0nCJmKV7LG6Yc1UlDHdmiA"

    // define the secret key used to sign the token
    secretKey := []byte("P184S3h7Ugjl56l31qeJ4FKvmBB4iikc")

    // parse the token and validate it
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        // validate the signing algorithm
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }

        // return the secret key
        return secretKey, nil
    })
    // check if there was an error parsing or validating the token
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing or validating token:", err)
        return
    }

    // check if the token is valid
    if !token.Valid {
        fmt.Println("Invalid token")
        return
    }

    // print the claims of the token
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    fmt.Println("Claims:", claims)
}
```

I don't know, but I think I got something wrong. The `alg` of the token is `RS256`. And I tried to get the public key from my realm on keycloak.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```golang
// define the secret key used to sign the token
secretKey := []byte("P184S3h7Ugjl56l31qeJ4FKvmBB4iikc")
```

The comment and the variable name here are misleading. According to the code in your demo, this is the public key which is used to validate the token.

Another issue is that `jwt.Parse` expects the `keyFunc` to return an instance of `*rsa.PublicKey`. The public key copied from Keycloak is a base64-encoded key, which should be parsed first. `parseKeycloakRSAPublicKey` below shows how to parse it.

Here comes the full demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"

    jwt "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func main() {
    // example token to validate
    tokenString := "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6MXdOWU9YVFRpd2RhQjJyS1NqNElrUG1YTDJHbXVTOVFRNERJeXpWbWlrIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2ODIxMTQ3MjgsImlhdCI6MTY4MjExNDQyOCwianRpIjoiZDE5NGZlMmEtZDUyOC00YjhhLWI3OWItODEwNDMxNWExNzIxIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL3JlYWxtcy9BcnFncmlmbyIsImF1ZCI6ImFjY291bnQiLCJzdWIiOiJmOWExMTYxYi00YzhiLTRmM2MtODViYy0xYmM1MDE0MWFmNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhenAiOiJ3ZWItYXBwIiwiYWNyIjoiMSIsImFsbG93ZWQtb3JpZ2lucyI6WyIvKiJdLCJyZWFsbV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsiZGVmYXVsdC1yb2xlcy1hcnFncmlmbyIsIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIiwidW1hX2F1dGhvcml6YXRpb24iXX0sInJlc291cmNlX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJ3ZWItYXBwIjp7InJvbGVzIjpbInVtYV9wcm90ZWN0aW9uIl19LCJhY2NvdW50Ijp7InJvbGVzIjpbIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50IiwibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQtbGlua3MiLCJ2aWV3LXByb2ZpbGUiXX19LCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJjbGllbnRJZCI6IndlYi1hcHAiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImNsaWVudEhvc3QiOiIxNzIuMTcuMC4xIiwicHJlZmVycmVkX3VzZXJuYW1lIjoic2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LXdlYi1hcHAiLCJjbGllbnRBZGRyZXNzIjoiMTcyLjE3LjAuMSJ9.vqFWx5mMESEMww8E5t1J8ZmoCw1R9qv1qlgaYaG7FQcd8B_sN223cDYMoqJF5y-Xv9zaJ094fUmyDtJHv-ZTkxw3R9AtjG0cCjqMxgBn1X2irlNYEmR5ZX73YXDUxY6XuABLyTGdh00bEcaUIyFR1Pver2UDjMf2okcV1FgEd0Z_94j4pjqtcY0nbsWIKnLoVoor7QV6ytWRpMG25DvrSVxciaOpogOHlUhaWtTfMz-mvfFg64i_S6rIuT84APnVe6weAuj92YS6bUzBif_gcgNeMdLrJChxWdPMK9G5mDAgLOqUv-X5fPOw1arigInV0nCJmKV7LG6Yc1UlDHdmiA"

    // The base64-encoded public key downloaded from Keycloak.
    // The screenshot in the question shows the correct place to get it.
    // It's much longer than "P184S3h7Ugjl56l31qeJ4FKvmBB4iikc".
    base64EncodedPublicKey := `replaced with the public key downloaded from Keycloak`
    publicKey, err := parseKeycloakRSAPublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }

        // return the public key that is used to validate the token.
        return publicKey, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing or validating token:", err)
        return
    }

    if !token.Valid {
        fmt.Println("Invalid token")
        return
    }

    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    fmt.Println("Claims:", claims)
}

func parseKeycloakRSAPublicKey(base64Encoded string) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    buf, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64Encoded)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    parsedKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    publicKey, ok := parsedKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    if ok {
        return publicKey, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected key type %T", publicKey)
}
```